# How to call c++ Oppencv project from c# web service?

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, dll, opencv

I have implemented image recognition algorithm as OpenCV c++ project and also i have C# web service.I want to call my c++ Opencv project from my c# web service. this is how my project should work.from mobile it send image to the c# web service.Then i need to call the Opencv c++ project in order to do the image recognition. I tried to do this by using DLL.If you think using the DLL is best method can you please tell how i convert my Opencv c++ projetc into DLL OR are there any other method.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use PInvoke to do your job. Haven't used it, but from what I know, this is the way to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.In Pinvoke its need to use a dll.But again the problem is I don't know how to convert my opencv project into a dll.Can i convert my whole project into dll at once with out doing any change for my opencv pproject.

Comment: @JnG I haven't worked with C++ and open CV (just some C# and Emgu CV). I will send this link to a friend who works with open CV and maybe he can answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a C++ DLL project where you will write the image recognition part of the project. You can check out this tutorial on how to create a C++ DLL project with Visual Studio: [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You should create a class in that DLL file, and you will be able to use that class to process an image. By using PInvoke, you will be able to use that class in a C# project. Here is a great tutorial on how to use a C++ class from a DLL in a C# project: [How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class). I have used solution A from that article in many projects to call C++ code from C#.

In order to convert an existing C++ project to a DLL, you can change its output type. Go to Project->Properties, and in that window you need to go to Configuration Properties->General, and change Configuration type to Dynamic Library (.dll), like in this image: [image: Project properties DLL]

After that, you need to expose your class or functions to be exported from the dll. I strongly suggest you start a new dll project (folow the first link) and work from there, because the AppWizard will create some code for you and it will be easier.